# Why does a proxy class need to extends java.lang.reflect.Proxy

Tags: java, dynamic, proxy

I found the definition process of the proxy class， But why the automatically generated proxy class must be a subclass of Proxy?

sun.misc.ProxyGenerator.java,

```
/** name of the superclass of proxy classes */
private final static String superclassName = "java/lang/reflect/Proxy";
......
try {
        /*
         * Write all the items of the "ClassFile" structure.
         * See JVMS section 4.1.
         */
                                    // u4 magic;
        dout.writeInt(0xCAFEBABE);
                                    // u2 minor_version;
        dout.writeShort(CLASSFILE_MINOR_VERSION);
                                    // u2 major_version;
        dout.writeShort(CLASSFILE_MAJOR_VERSION);

        cp.write(dout);             // (write constant pool)

                                    // u2 access_flags;
        dout.writeShort(accessFlags);
                                    // u2 this_class;
        dout.writeShort(cp.getClass(dotToSlash(className)));


        // why jdk do this ???
                                    // u2 super_class;
        dout.writeShort(cp.getClass(superclassName));

                                    // u2 interfaces_count;
        dout.writeShort(interfaces.length);
                                    // u2 interfaces[interfaces_count];
        for (Class<?> intf : interfaces) {
            dout.writeShort(cp.getClass(
                dotToSlash(intf.getName())));
        }
```

Comment: Sun/Oracle decided to have some common aspects inherited from a common ancestor class named `Proxy` instead of copying it into every individual proxy class. Out of curiosity: why do you ask? Want to write your own proxies?

Comment: As we know, JDK does not support the dynamic proxy of the `class`, only supporting the`interface`, This is the cause of this. Otherwise, There is not much commonality between the dynamic proxy class and the `Proxy`， I don't understand why JDK designs this